# How do I add a new contact using Salesforce1 mobile app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, contact

I downloaded the Salesforce1 mobile app and can't find how I to add a new contact using the app. Is this possible or is the mobile app functionality limited to only viewing data?

Answer (score 2):

No you can do almost everything with this app.

Click on top left menu icon and find Contact object:

[image: Navigation]

By clicking "New" button you can add new contact.

[image: New button]

Comment: Are you Using Salesforce 1 App in iPhone/iPad ? I have Installed same app in Samsung Tab 3, I am also not getting 'New' Button in any Object

Comment: @user40138 It is Google Nexus 5 screenshot taken few minutes ago.

Comment: Whether app is showing has Chatter OR Salesforce 1, In my Case it shows has Chatter Even if I install the other

Comment: Do I have to Config Anywhere To get New Button

Comment: @user40138 No i didn't take extra steps to get "New" button.

Comment: I'm using it both on an iPad and on an Android phone and the "ADD NEW" button for Contacts isn't showing up on either of them. It shows up for Companies but not for Contacts. Is this a permissions issue from within Salesforce admin?

Comment: I don't think there are specific permissions. If you can do it in salesforce, you should be able to do it in the app.

Comment: @Liz In iPad/tablets Salesoforce1 functions slightly different compare to smartphones. check there is different navigation for adding new contact.

Comment: @regal I am getting it has chatter bcoz of my OS according to this comment in Play Store [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter)

Comment: Might be the user doesn't have permission to create a contact?

Answer (score 0):

Has your user got permissions to create contacts? If so you should be able to create contacts from Salesforce1 if no you won't see the "New" button and you wont be able to create contacts from Salesforce1 and either from desktop-web browser.
Check your user, the profile and the permission sets that it has.
Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the new button of contacts page is overridden
Go to > Setup > Contacts > Buttons, Links, and Actions

Now check whether the 'new' button has default setting(No Override)